# C# How to check if any datagridview checkbox is check

Tags: c#

I want to fire an event when any of the datagridviewcheckbox is checked. I tried the foreach but it only trigger when all the datagridviewcheck is checked.
I want to fire an event if **any** of the datagridviewcheckboxcell is checked.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvLocal.Rows)
{
    if ((Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true))
    {
        //
    }               
}
```

Comment: What is "triggering" this foreach? I think we're missing some context here.

Comment: That code looks like it will do something when it finds the first item that's checked, you only need a `break` inside the `if` so it stops checking when one is found. If you have that, then there must be something else.

Comment: I dont know which event will i put this code on.

Comment: I just want to show a messagebox when I check any checkboxcell in datagridview.

Answer (score 1):

Use the cellcontentclicked event of the datagridview 
Also use the CurrentCellDirtystateChanged to make sure the last click is commited

```
  void grd_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (grd.IsCurrentCellDirty)
                    grd.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }


    private void grd_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) //compare to checkBox column index
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cbx = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)grd[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
                if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(cbx.Value) && (bool)cbx.Value == true)
                {
                    //checkBox is checked - do the code in here!
                }
                else
                {
                    //if checkBox is NOT checked (unchecked)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
 DataGridViewCheckBoxCell check = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[1];
 if (check.Value  == check.TrueValue)
  {
    //dosomething
  }
 else
  {
   //dosomething
  }
}
```

Comment: Error 5 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool' C:\Users\MOMO\Desktop\MLQ System 9.26\MLQ SYTSTEM 9.26\MLQSystem\UpdateVisitors.cs 924 21 MLQSystem

Comment: try to use  '=' instead of '=='

Answer (score 0):

Trigger CellValueChanged

```
private void dgvProducts_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvProducts.DataSource != null)
        {
            if (dgvProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "True")
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
               //do something
            }
        }
    }
```